# C#:Unity:Having trouble reference Rigidbody2d from different script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, game-physics

My scene has a main character, a balloon and a tether. I have a spring joint 2d connected to the balloon and I want to be able to change the connected body to the object the player clicks on. So far I have the following 2 scripts, one for the balloon and one for the connecting body:

Balloon:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class BalloonTethering : MonoBehaviour {

    public SpringJoint2D theSpringJoint;
    public Rigidbody2D theTether;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        theSpringJoint.connectedBody = theTether;
    }
}
```

Connecting Body:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TetherAny : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject mainBalloon;
    public Rigidbody2D iAmATether = new Rigidbody2D();

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        mainBalloon.GetComponents<BalloonTethering>();
        iAmATether = this.gameObject.GetComponents<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    void OnMouseDown(){
        BalloonTethering.theTether = iAmATether;
    }
}
```

I keep getting the following two errors on the TetherAny script:

> (12,17): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Rigidbody2D[]' to 'UnityEngine.Rigidbody2D'
>
> (21,34): error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member 'BalloonTethering.theTether'

If anyone could tell me where I'm going wrong it would be much appreciated :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From the first error line I can tell that GetComponents() will return multiple Rigidbody2D object, not only one.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponents.html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Use these two links to understand what is actually happening.

On the second one.. You are trying to access a member of a class of which you don't have the object to (that's not how you access other objects members)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9afc042.aspx

It seems to me that you should learn how to program the basics first, honestly. But that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

> (12,17): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Rigidbody2D[]' to 'UnityEngine.Rigidbody2D'

GetComponents returns a LIST of Rigidbodies. You cannot assign an entire list to one object. You need to use GetComponent, not GetComponents. Singular. The '[]' after Rigidbody2D in the error denotes that it is a list, not a single object.

> (21,34): error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member 'BalloonTethering.theTether'

This is because you never tell it what BalloonTethering you want it to reference. You need to use GetComponent() on the balloon object. There are other problems here, I'm surprised you aren't getting more errors. As soon as you attempt to access any of these variables there will be problems! I'll fix up the first script to get you on your way

```
    using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class BalloonTethering : MonoBehaviour {

    public SpringJoint2D theSpringJoint;
    public Rigidbody2D theTether;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
          theSpringJoint =  this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpringJoint2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

You'll need to assign an object to theTether if you want anything to happen when you make it the connectedBody